# Why 2 index.php pages here?

Tags: php

trying to implement the MCV based off Dary's video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2yeK6LwSII
I can't understand why we have an index.php in the public folder and index.php in the view/pages folder  I honestly can't figure out how the one in the view/pages gets called.
I am trying to configure this on IIS as well
https://github.com/Darynazar/MVCFramework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public/index.php` is the entry place of your app.

all other PHP files will include after that, so the `index.php` in view is not the enry point. you can rename it to whatever you want.

Comment: it is strange, but it's really the first tutorial that I was able to follow along most of the way.  they only thing I am trying to do is make it work with IIS instead of what he's using.

Comment: it's better you use nginx or apache because for passing every uri to index.php you need special settings

Comment: I will check this out.